How to ask a professor to join their research lab?
I am intending to apply for a PhD, but I lack prior research experience. I’m currently getting my master’s, but all of the labs at my university are full.
Therefore I am considering to join a lab at another university. The professor doesn’t know me; I will be cold-emailing them. How do I ask to join their lab? I don’t want to be paid, I simply want the experience. What do I do? Should I even reach out to this professor?

Write an email telling how you can be useful, and prepare for rejection or not hearing back. Try other places.

Suggest an internship (unpaid, for starters); topic of the prof's area.Maybe they may be interested. Highlight why you would add to the lab and what they would gain from this. I assume you do not need a visa for that, or better pick a formal option. Are you looking for a PhD?

Yes a PhD, but I don’t have enough research experience

If you have a masters, what level of research experience does that lab expect more than your masters?

I have recently had several (good) students suggest something like this to me. I rejected, essentially because it seemed like a probable breach of labor laws, and a breach of academic student/teacher etiquette in any case. It smells of student exploitation. Students should always either get a degree / course / whatever for working for you, or be paid and have a contract.

The masters is not competitive. There are students with publications and a few years worth of lab/research experience who I will be facing during application cycle. The master is not enough- as I’ve been told from admissions counselors for PhD programs I want to apply to.

@DaGuk Unfortunately, that doesn't entitle you to work in someone else's lab. Your next step is to get a job as an RA for a few years until you feel ready to apply to PhD programs.

What country are you applying in?

United States. I am a U.S. citizen

@AzorAhai-him- I’m confused how entitlement is even a topic here?

"All of the labs at my university are full" -- I don't work in a laboratory science, so this comment might be naive -- but this seems like a serious problem to me. Are others in your degree program also not finding lab placements? I would talk with your graduate director, student ombudsman, grad student union if there is one, etc. Good luck.

@DaGuk: I think you are confusing being entitled in general with being entitled to some specific privilege.

@DaGuk Perhaps I could have chosen a different word, but my point is that you are unlikely to be taken in as a student at this point. To get the experience you need, apply for jobs.

It's possible working without pay is not legal in your jurisdiction.
It's very likely the professor would like to (or is compelled to) focus on mentoring students at their same institution.
A cold email has a low success rate in the best of circumstances, these aren't the best circumstances, but that's all you really have. In your email be brief and to the point, use maybe a sentence to say what you want and a sentence to say why you're interested in that lab, attach your CV, and then plan not to hear a response (that's okay, you're taking a shot in the dark).

It's important to note that what makes this "not legal" is the wording "join your research group", which implies, or at least sounds dangerously close to, working for somebody unpaid. If you ask for collaboration / mentoring, your chances may be higher (still not great, but higher).

@xLeitix I clarified that the part that is possibly not legal is the working without pay part.

You certainly have an uphill battle. Each student a professor advises costs, on average, perhaps 2-3 hours per week if you include advising meetings, paperwork, reading thesis drafts, etc. Why would a professor offer this amount of time if it isn't part of their job duties at the university they're at? Why would a department agree to a professor using this much time if the university does not get the student's tuition or the state's subsidy for students?
In short, you're asking the person to do something out of the good of their heart, using time they could be spending with their family, gardening, reading books, riding bikes, or hanging out with friends. I think it's unlikely you're going to be successful -- regardless of how exactly you phrase your email.

I think this answer is a little too pessimistic - many professors have more ideas than they have time for, and are happy to take students to implement them.

@justauser - and there are likely local students they are familiar with already available, rather than going outside for an  unknown commodity.

Yes unfortunate situation. I need research experience to get research experience. There’s no opportunity at my current university and if I try at another university it’s a no. I’ll probably have to find another career cause without the research I’m not competitive or qualified for a PhD

@DaGuk You'll have to switch universities, then.

You note that you are in the US. I suggest you apply to a variety of doctoral programs across the country. Cast a wide net, and you are likely to get into some doctoral programs. It may not be at your dream destination, but it is certainly better than being unpaid labor in a situation that is frankly not productive for you or your voluntary advisor.
While I work in a different field, I do get requests for remote supervision from students wanting to apply theory to our experimental work (usually foreign, or foreign students who got into a US program that is lower ranked/resourced than they had hoped). I always decline. This is not a reasonable arrangement, and frankly it violates many of the Conflict of Interest clauses at my University. I am using time and other resources to unofficially mentor a graduate student for whom the University can claim nothing (no degree conferred, no other metrics met).
